# extract run command from intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

Hi I want to run a code on a remote server where IntelliJ Idea is not installed. My code needs a lot of classpath parameter which I handle that with IntelliJ Idea in my local computer. Now how can I export all running parameter and actually a something like:

```
$ java -cp ... Main.class ...
```

from Intellij Idea to use on remote server?

thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at some build tool like Maven, Ant, Gradle or Buildr. The tool can be used to perform consistent builds, set up classpaths and so on.

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ and all IDEs should have nothing to do with your deployment.  You need to package it properly as an executable JAR.  IntelliJ can be told to add that to the JAR manifest.  Figure out how to tell it so.